# Why does subprocess hang when reading from stdout

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a script called 'my_script.py' with the following contents:

```
my_input = ''
while my_input != 'quit':
    my_input = raw_input()
    print(my_input)
```

Then in the console, the following commands:

```
from subprocess import *
p1 = Popen(['python', 'my_script.py'], stdin=PIPE)
p1.stdin.write('some words\n')
```

prints "some words", but if instead I write

```
from subprocess import *
p2 = Popen(['python', 'my_script.py'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
p2.stdin.write('some words\n')
p2.stdout.readline()
```

the shell will hang and I have to terminate it manually. How can I get this to work if I want to be able to access the stdout of the script? I'm using python2.7

Edit: To clarify my question, the above snippet will run properly for other executables that have an I/O loop (the particular one I'm working with is the stockfish chess engine). Is there a way I can modify my_script.py such that the above snippet will run properly? Using

```
Popen(['python3', 'my_script.py'], ...)
```

will work, but is it not possible using Python 2.7?

Answer (score 0):

It could happen due to deadlock in `readline`.

You need to use `communicate` method to read asynchronously.

Example:

```
 def run_shell_command(cmd, params):
        cmdline = [cmd]
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmdline, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
        if p.returncode != 0:
            raise RuntimeError("%r failed, status code %s stdout %r stderr %r" % (
                cmd, p.returncode, stdout, stderr))
        return stdout.strip()  # This is the stdout from the shell command
```

To execute command in background you can use following example:

```
def run_shell_remote_command_background(cmd):
    cmdline = [cmd]
    cmdline = cmdline + params.split(' ')
    subprocess.Popen(['cmdline'])
```

Comment: unfortunately `communicate` only allows one round of input to the subprocess, where I need multiple.

Comment: @AdamVenis do you mean multiline output?

Comment: no, in your example if i wanted send input with `p.communicate('foo')`, I wouldn't then be able to send `p.communicate('bar')` afterwards without opening a new subprocess. This is what I understand to be the drawback of using `communicate`, because it waits for the subprocess to finish executing entirely.

Comment: @AdamVenis Got it, you want to execute subprocess in the background. Then `Popen(['python3', 'my_script.py'])` will be good from 2.7 as well